# Javascript addition not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop, logic, smarty

I am building a E-shopping site using SMATY template engine . In my viewCart page, I have calculated the price for individual items accoring to the quantity,using javascript but unable to calculate the total value .

```
{foreach name = feach item = k from = $res key = ind}

   <!-- PRODUCT INFO -->

   <div class="cleaner_h20">&nbsp;</div>

   <div id="iteminfo">
   <span class="styleblue">{$k->brand} {$k->model}</span>
    </div>
     <div id="itemsmall">
     Rs. <span id="pro_prc{$ind}">{$k->price}</span>
   </div>
    <div id="itemsmall">


 <select id="qty{$ind}" name="qty" onchange="change_price('{$ind}')">

       <option name="1" value="1">1</option>
       <option name="2" value="2">2</option>
       <option name="3" value="3">3</option>
       <option name="4" value="4">4</option>
  </select>


     </div>
    <div id="itemsmall_long"> <a href="#"><img src="{$path_css}images/remove.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="itemsmall">
    Rs.<span id="prc{$ind}">  {$k->price}</span>
   </div>

    <div class="cleaner_h20">&nbsp;</div>


       {literal}
       <script>
        function change_price(ind)
        {

         var y=document.getElementById("pro_prc"+ind).innerHTML;
         //alert(y);
        var z=document.getElementById("qty"+ind).value;
           // alert(z);
         x=y*z;
        // alert(x);
         document.getElementById("prc"+ind).innerHTML=x;

        }
       </script>     
       {/literal}

{/foreach}
```

The above alert displays NaN . I am confused . May be my logic is not correct .

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt or parseFloat to transform strings into integers before multiplying them:

```
function change_price(ind)
{
   var y=parseInt(document.getElementById("pro_prc"+ind).innerHTML);
   //alert(y);
   var z=parseInt(document.getElementById("qty"+ind).value);
   // alert(z);
   x=y*z;
   // alert(x);
   document.getElementById("prc"+ind).innerHTML=x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to parse the string .

```
var y=document.getElementById("pro_prc"+ind).innerHTML
var y1=parseFloat(y).toFixed(4);
var z=document.getElementById("qty"+ind).value;
var z1=parseFloat(z).toFixed(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because y and z in your code stand for String, you should do it like : `var y = parseInt(y);` and `var z = parseInt(z)`;

Comment: I modified my code to `var y=document.getElementById("pro_prc"+ind).innerHTML;
    //alert(y);
    y = parseInt(y);
    
   var z=document.getElementById("qty"+ind).value;
         // alert(z);
    x=y*z;
   // alert(x);
   
   x = parseInt(x);
   
    document.getElementById("prc"+ind).innerHTML=x;
    
   
   var total = total + x;
   alert(total);`, but still same NaN appears !

Comment: Did You leave the comment sign `//` out?

Comment: I gave comment `//` only to alert `y` and `z`

Comment: Do you ensure that the argument `y` and `z`from back-end can be parsed into number correctly?

Comment: The value of `y` is from database and is of type `INT(11)` and `z` is from Select - Option drop down . `<select id="qty{$ind}" name="qty" onchange="change_price('{$ind}')">
  
        <option name="1" value="1">1</option>
        <option name="2" value="2">2</option>
        <option name="3" value="3">3</option>
        <option name="4" value="4">4</option>
   </select>`

Comment: In the code `var y=document.getElementById("pro_prc"+ind).innerHTML` the `ind` how and where do you get it?

Comment: `ind` is index for the `foreach` loop in `Smarty` . `{foreach name = feach item = k from = $res key = ind}`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Smarty.Sorry to not help you.I hope you can tell me the reason if you get it.

Comment: If your script in .php not in seperately .js, `ind` should recorrect `{$ind}`.Have a try.